# Figures won't stay where they should using LaTex

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm using TeXnic Center, but I'm having an issue with getting my figures where I want them. I've used [h!] etc but when I write something else it will put it before and partially after my figures, i.e. not where I want it. Is there a way I can ensure my text is where I want it?

Comment: Used [H], seemed to work so far.

Comment: Or, as a duplicate of [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31)

Comment: `[H]` is a possibility but more natural really is not to use `figure` at all, the _only_ purpose of the figure environment is to tell Latex the content is a _float_ ie it may be moved to help with page breaking. `[!h]` is quite likely to send the float to the end of the document 9and generate a warning that it has been changed to `[!ht]` better to use `[htp]`

Comment: Also, for reference: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned